# If $[G:H]$ is a prime $p$ and $H \triangleleft G$, show that there exists an element $a \in G$ such that $G=\cup_{i=0}^{p-1}a^iH$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.If $[G:H]$ is a prime $p$ and $H \triangleleft G$, show that there exists an element $a \in G$ such that $G=\cup_{i=0}^{p-1}a^iH$. I have no idea on how to start. Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think any element $a\in G\setminus H$ would do it.

Then, $aH\ne H$, and $G/H\cong \Bbb (Z_p,+)$ (because $[G:H]=p$ and the only group of order $p$ is the cyclic one), so in the composite homomorphism $f:G\to G/H\cong\Bbb Z_p$ (via $a\mapsto aH$), we have that $f(a)\ne 0$, so $f(a)$ generates $\Bbb Z_p$, and
$$G=f^{-1}(\Bbb Z_p)=f^{-1}(0)\cup f^{-1}(1)\cup f^{-1}(2)\cup\dots = H\cup aH\cup a^2H\cup\dots $$

Comment: Excellent answer, +1.

Comment: what motivates you to think of the map ?

Comment: Homomorphisms are always useful. Anyway I'm quite sure that $H$ needs not be normal subgroup -- easiest probably by studying the action of $G$ on the $p$ element set of (left) cosets.